# How to replace certain character combination with another in OpenOffice?

Tags: replace, find, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'd like to replace wrongly formatted text in multiple documents. Instead of the proper way like this

```
»Citation«
```

words have been cited like this

```
«Citation»
```

(or some other combination like »Citation»)

Now, I know there is the Regular Expression, which I'd use like this for the opening mark:

```
«[A-Z]
```

But how does the replace string look like? It doesn't work with "»", neither with "»[A-Z]", neither with "»*"....

I guess there is a very simple solution, but I haven't found any answer in the different forums. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for:

```
«([A-Z]+)»
```

Replace with:

```
»$1«
```

For documentation, look under `( )` in the Character column at: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions.